# The minimum of $f(x)=1+x+\cdots+x^{2n}$

Tags: polynomials

For the function $$
f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}{x^k}
$$
I think this function has no zeros, and if ${f(x_0)}$ is the minimum point, then ${x_0\in \left[-1,0 \right] }$.

For $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$ and $1+x+x^2$, I can get the minimum by calculating $f'(x)$ and then using the root fomula. But this method doesn't work for $n\geqslant 3$ since there is no root fomula for equations higher than the fifth degree.

I have no idea for the situation where  $n\geqslant 3$, so any advice could be helpful

Comment: A potentially useful fact: f(x)=(2 n+1)  Hypergeometric2F1[1,-2 n,2,1-x]. In this forms derivatives are easy to evaluate.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson I am a freshman thus I know little about the Hypergeometric function. I am still learning it on wiki. Can you just show me the result or the step.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson. Could you eleborate ?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Could you explain how you find derivatives because I think f(x)=(2 n+1) Hypergeometric2F1[1,-2 n,2,1-x] is same as (x^(2n+1)-1)/(x-1), thus changing the form cannot simplify it.

Comment: More funny stuff in the update !

Comment: @SaltedFishKing I originally thought higher order derivatives of $f$ might play a role in this problem.  Since there are compact closed-form expressions for derivatives of ${_2F}_1$ to any order I thought that reformulating $f$ in this manner may help. It was just a passing comment and probably not as useful as I originally thought.

Comment: @SaltedFishKing Would you mind sharing the motivation for this question? I am interested in the application you had for finding the minimum of $f(x)$.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson  Sorry for replying late. I was interested by a phenomenon that 1+x+x^2 can be changed into (x+1/2)^2+3/4, similarly, 1+x+...+x^4= x^2(x+1/2)^2+3(x/2+1/3)^2+2/3, and this method can be applied when x^6. So I guess 1+x+x^2+...x^(2k)=x^(2k-2)(x+1/2)^2+x^(2k-4)(...)^2+...+A_2k. So the f(x) can be changed into a form the sum of many non-negative number + A_2k. By using induction proof and sequence knowledge, the An can be find out, which is (n+2)/(2n+2), So I guess I can get the closed form of fmin. Furthermore, after being helped, I probably get when n->infinity that fmin=1/2.

Comment: Although the proof is still open, it looks like your problem does have a closed-form in terms of hypergeometric functions.  See updated answer.

Comment: Great great thank to all of you who contributes to this question. Thank you for turning my little thought into such a formal and meaningful answer.

Comment: @SaltedFishKing An exact solution to the problem has been proven. If you would like your actual name to appear in the article citation please email me at the address given in the arXiv paper linked in my answer.

Comment: @SaltedFishKing The final solution to your problem is now available on arXiv as detailed in the updated answer.  This was a very fun problem and I'm still surprised that a closed-from exists.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@ClaudeLeibovici and I had a lot of fun with this one. The link to the arXiv article below provides a derivation of the minimum of this polynomial for any $n\in\Bbb N$.

[Exact and approximate solutions to the minimum of $1+x+\cdots+x^{2n}$](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.00135)

---

**Summary of paper:**

To find the minimum of this polynomial, denoted $f_{2n}(x)$, we first derived the relationship
$$
\inf_x f_{2n}(x)=\frac{1+2n}{1+2n(1-x_{2n})},
$$
with $x_{2n}$ being the argument of the minimum. It was then shown that $x_{2n}$ satisfies
$$
x_{2n}^{2n}\left(1-x_{2n}+\tfrac{1}{2n}\right)-\tfrac{1}{2n}=0,
$$
and an exact solution of this equation was subsequently found via Lagrange inversion. For the purposes of numerical computation we also derived a faster converging perturbation series for $x_{2n}$.

Comment: Great thanks. Not offensive, so, in general, how can we judge that one problem/equation have a closed-form solution. Is there any kind of features to hint us to use numerical method? I mean that if there doesn't exist a closed-form solution, it will be wasting time to find it.

Comment: Interesting, for sure. I thought at a time about things similar but I bumped in the problem : *"where to place $\epsilon$ ?"* that you solved.

Comment: This is beautiful solution, for sure.

Comment: More I read your answer $\implies$ more I am impressed !

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Wow. Seriously? That's a huge complement. Thank you Claude! I have never used perturbation series before and thought they were really fascinating. I was hoping it would reveal some sort of pattern in the coefficients. There may be one, I just couldn't see it.

Comment: You **mus**t publish this work. Add also the minimum value of the function. It is so simple to compute (as I wrote it in my update).

Comment: I am a serious old man, trust me. This is a remarkable work. May I confess that I am (a little, little bit jalous ? Cheers

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Well I see some of your ideas in the update so if you have an idea of what journal might like this I am going to request you come on as a coauthor. And btw, there appears to be a rather straightforward way to clean the whole thing up to get coefficients of higher orders without it becoming a gigantic mess. If you're interested let me know!

Comment: Yes, I am ! No idea about a possible journal (I published a lot of papers but never in a math journal). At least ArXiv

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Great. I say we flesh out a few details and write it up. Maybe put it on ArXiv and then find a home for it. I only expect it to be a few pages. How shall I send you a first draft?

Comment: My e-mail address is in my profile. May be it could be a good idea that you change to $n$ to $2n$ to go back to the problem.

Answer (score 7):

It seems possible to generate an *estimate* of the value of $x$ where the function
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}{x^k}=\frac{x^{2 n+1}-1}{x-1}$$ is minimum.
As shown in other answers, the problem is to *approximate* the zero of function
$$g(x)=2nx^{2n+1}-(2n+1)x^{2n}+1$$
This have been done using the first iteration of  an high order iterative method starting with $x=-1$ as an initial guess. The result is given by
$$x_0=-\frac{256 n^6+10240 n^5+75296 n^4+212560 n^3+273764 n^2+159400 n+33199}{2 (2 n+3)
   \left(64 n^5+2688 n^4+20224 n^3+53604 n^2+56320 n+20001\right)}$$

Now, one single interation of Newton method is supposed to sufficiently polish the solution (it would not be any problem to use Halley or Householder methods in place of Newton).

Below are reported some results ($x_1$ by Newton).
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
n & x_0 & x_1 & \text{solution} \\
 1 & -0.500137 & -0.500000 &  -0.500000 \\
 2 & -0.605614 & -0.605830 &  -0.605830 \\
 3 & -0.669716 & -0.670334 &  -0.670332 \\
 4 & -0.713566 & -0.714543 &  -0.714538 \\
 5 & -0.745773 & -0.747064 &  -0.747054 \\
 6 & -0.770592 & -0.772160 &  -0.772142 \\
 7 & -0.790396 & -0.792205 &  -0.792178 \\
 8 & -0.806624 & -0.808643 &  -0.808605 \\
 9  & -0.820203 & -0.822403 &  -0.822353 \\
 10 & -0.831760 & -0.834116 &  -0.834053 \\
 11 & -0.841736 & -0.844223 &  -0.844148 \\
 12 & -0.850449 & -0.853047 &  -0.852958 \\
 13 & -0.858136 & -0.860826 &  -0.860724 \\
 14 & -0.864977 & -0.867742 &  -0.867627 \\
 15 & -0.871111 & -0.873936 &  -0.873809 \\
 16 & -0.876648 & -0.879520 &  -0.879381 \\
 17 & -0.881675 & -0.884583 &  -0.884433 \\
 18 & -0.886264 & -0.889197 &  -0.889037 \\
 19 & -0.890473 & -0.893421 &  -0.893252 \\
 20 & -0.894349 & -0.897304 &  -0.897127 \\
 21 & -0.897932 & -0.900888 &  -0.900703 \\
 22 & -0.901257 & -0.904206 &  -0.904015 \\
 23 & -0.904351 & -0.907289 &  -0.907091 \\
 24 & -0.907239 & -0.910161 &  -0.909958 \\
 25 & -0.909942 & -0.912843 &  -0.912636
\end{array}
\right)$$

It is possible to do better for $x_0$ at the price of an higher order method.

**Edit**

For the fun of it, I used the same procedure with two more orders. The result write, just as before,
$$x_0=-\frac{\sum_{k=0}^8 a_k\,n^k}{\sum_{k=0}^8 b_k\,n^k}$$ and the coefficients are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & a_k & b_k \\
 0 & 2300106 & 8278851 \\
 1 & 13284828 & 37098288 \\
 2 & 30007592 & 67149620 \\
 3 & 34417264 & 63318640 \\
 4 & 21546112 & 33284272 \\
 5 & 7272832 & 9611392 \\
 6 & 1199488 & 1382080 \\
 7 & 73216 & 75520 \\
 8 & 512 & 512
\end{array}
\right)$$

Just to give an idea, for $n=25$ this produces for $x_0$ a value of $-0.912088$.

**Update**

Up to now, we just focused on the value of $x$ for which $f(x)$ is minimum. What is interesting if that when $f'(x_0)=0$ by elimination we have the simple
$$f(x_0)=\frac{2 n+1}{1+2 n(1-x_0)}$$

Using the last set of coefficients given in the edit, we have
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
n & f_{\text{min}}^{\text{est}} & f_{\text{min}}^{\text{calc}}  & x_0^{\text{calc}}& x_0^{\text{est}}\\
 1 & 0.749996 & 0.750000& -0.500000 & -0.500011 \\
 2 & 0.673570 & 0.673553& -0.605830 & -0.605782 \\
 3 & 0.635115 & 0.635094& -0.670332 & -0.670271 \\
 4 & 0.611584 & 0.611567& -0.714538 & -0.714486 \\
 5 & 0.595555 & 0.595543& -0.747054 & -0.747017 \\
 6 & 0.583866 & 0.583858& -0.772142 & -0.772117 \\
 7 & 0.574928 & 0.574922& -0.792178 & -0.792159 \\
 8 & 0.567852 & 0.567846& -0.808605 & -0.808586 \\
  9 & 0.562099 & 0.562091& -0.822353 & -0.822327 \\
 10 & 0.557321 & 0.557309& -0.834053 & -0.834013 \\
 11 & 0.553284 & 0.553267& -0.844148 & -0.844089 \\
 12 & 0.549825 & 0.549801& -0.852958 & -0.852876 \\
 13 & 0.546825 & 0.546793& -0.860724 & -0.860614 \\
 14 & 0.544196 & 0.544156& -0.867627 & -0.867487 \\
 15 & 0.541872 & 0.541823& -0.873809 & -0.873636 \\
 16 & 0.539802 & 0.539743& -0.879381 & -0.879173 \\
 17 & 0.537945 & 0.537876& -0.884433 & -0.884189 \\
 18 & 0.536269 & 0.536190& -0.889037 & -0.888755 \\
 19 & 0.534749 & 0.534660& -0.893252 & -0.892932 \\
 20 & 0.533363 & 0.533263& -0.897127 & -0.896769 \\
 21 & 0.532094 & 0.531984& -0.900703 & -0.900306 \\
 22 & 0.530926 & 0.530807& -0.904015 & -0.903580 \\
 23 & 0.529850 & 0.529719& -0.907091 & -0.906618 \\
 24 & 0.528852 & 0.528712& -0.909958 & -0.909447 \\
 25 & 0.527926 & 0.527777& -0.912636 & -0.912088
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Update**

After [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4112014/can-this-equation-be-written-in-terms-of-x/4113134?noredirect=1#comment8504334_4113134) (which looks quite similar), I thought that it could be interesting to look for the zero of function
$$h(x)=\log \left((2 n+1) x^{2 n}-2 n x^{2 n+1}\right)$$ Expanding it as a series around $x=-1$ and using series reversion, we end with
$$x=-1+z+\sum_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac {P_k(n) } { 2^{k-1}\, k! \,(4 n+1)^{k-1} }\,z^k$$ with
$$z=\frac{(4 n+1) \log (4 n+1)}{4 n (2 n+1)}$$
The first $P_k(n)$ are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 8 n+1 \\
 3 & 64 n^2+8 n-1 \\
 4 & 512 n^3+32 n^2-24 n-1 \\
 5 & 4096 n^4+256 n^3+32 n^2+104 n+13
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for your efforts on numerical methods. I used computer program to calculate in your way and find out the zeros. Furthermore, I am interested in whether there exists a  closed-form expression of an analytic expression. One commenter recommended me to use  f(x)=(2 n+1) Hypergeometric2F1[1,-2 n,2,1-x], but it seems difficult.

Comment: @SaltedFishKing. I do not see how rewrite $f(x)$ as the hypergeometric function could be of any help for the computation of any derivative. Do not dream too much about a closed form solution.

Comment: Anyway, thanks. I think that f(x)=(2 n+1) Hypergeometric2F1[1,-2 n,2,1-x] is just same as (x^(2n+1)-1)/(x-1).

Comment: @SaltedFishKing. For sure, it is ! This is why I asked AaronHendrickson to elaborate.

Comment: It is true that $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}x^k=(2n+1) {_2F}_1(1,-2n,2,1-x)$ which can be derived by expanding $1-x^{2n+1}=1-(1-(1-x))^{2n+1}$ with binomial theorem and then using hypergeometric series to compare. As per my comment above, I thought it was going to be helpful but it didn't accomplish much.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I was thinking that perturbation series for the root could also be a path forward. Did you consider this option?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson. No, I did not because I don't see how to do. Could you put me on the track ? I am very interested by this post. Thanks in advance. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It is an interesting post! I posted a solution that obtains the first two coefficients of the perturbation series for the root. Tried to write a Mathematica script to generate more coefficients but was unsuccessful. There is a (probably quite small) chance that the perturbation series coefficients have a closed form.

Comment: Studying the beautiful paper of Hendrickson and Leibovici (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.00135.pdf) I noticed that the formula of theorem 2 can be simplified. When I enter the formula in Mathematica the hypergeometric functions with the structure $_{m+2}F_{m+1}$ are automatically reduced to a structure $_{m}F_{m-1}$. This could be made explicit in the formula.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze. Thank you for your kind words and for the interesting information.  Cheers :-)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it has no zeros, because $f(1)=2n+1\ne0$ and because, if $x\ne1$, $f(x)=\frac{x^{2n+1}-1}{x-1}$, which is never equal to $0$.

However, it is not true that the minimum is attained at some of $[0,1]$. For instance, of $n=2$, the the minimum is attained at about $-0.606$.

Comment: Thanks, I made a mistake when determining the interval of x, it should be -1 to 0, and I will change it.

Answer (score 3):

We can establish the minimum $x_0\in(-1,0)$ without explicitly finding it. This can be done by first re-writing, $$f(x)=\frac{x^{2n+1}-1}{x-1}$$ and then differentiating, $$f'(x)=\frac{2nx^{2n+1}-(2n+1)x^{2n}+1}{(x-1)^2}$$ Descarte's Rule of Signs reveals that $f'(x)$ has only one negative real root, call it $\alpha$. In particular, we see that $f'(-1)=-n$ and $f'(0)=1$, so we know $\alpha\in(-1,0)$, thus we know that $f(x)$ is decreasing (negative derivative) from $(-\infty,\alpha)$ and is increasing (positive derivative) from $(\alpha,0)$. Thus, since $f(x)>1$ for $x>0$ and $f(0)=1$ and $f(-1)=0$, then we are assured that $f(\alpha)<0$ and will be the absolute minimum of the whole function $f(x)$.

---

Finding $\alpha$ will most likely be done with an approximation (instead of closed form). There are a number of ways to approximate $\alpha$. One particularly straight forward approach, is to half the intervals testing if you are positive or negative at each step using the derivative. Since you know $\alpha\in[-1,0]$ this method will reach a really good approximation very quickly.

Comment: It seems that we could have almost the solution. Cheers :-)

Comment: @Claude Leibovici The OP indicated that they believed the minimum was a root of the derivative found in $[-1,0]$. I guess I was under the impression that the OP wanted to know if that statement is true and how we know that this statement is true for $n\ge 3$.