# Proving a polynomial to be positive for all real values

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to prove the following theorem:
$$\sum_{j=0}^{2n} (-x)^j >0\ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, n \in \mathbb{N}  $$
I have verified this theorem for $n=1$ (just a quadratic) and for $n=2$ (by simple factoring). However I'm stuck for higher values of $n$ and generalizing it. I'm thinking of proving this by proving it to be positive for one value of $x$ ($x=0$ should suffice) and then proving it has no real roots. I'm not sure how to do this though.

Comment: Have you attempted induction ? Do you know what that is ?

Comment: I do  not understand, what do you mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction

Comment: Related, almost duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4060608/42969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the principle of mathematical induction,
as suggested by @Digitallis in the comments,
we prove the stronger statement that, for real $x$ and natural $n$,
$$\sum_{j=0}^{2n} (-x)^j \ge \frac{1}{2}.$$

(1) Base step:
We have
\begin{align*}
1-x+x^2 &= (x-1/2)^2+3/4 \ge 3/4 \ge 1/2.
\end{align*}

(2) Inductive step:
We assume that
$\sum_{j=0}^{2k}(-x)^j \ge 1/2$
for some $k\ge 1$.
We must show that
$\sum_{j=0}^{2(k+1)}(-x)^j \ge 1/2$.
But
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^{2(k+1)}(-x)^j
    &= 1-x+\sum_{j=2}^{2n+2}(-x)^j \\ 
    &= 1-x+x^2\sum_{j=0}^{2n}(-x)^j \\ 
    &\ge 1-x+\frac12 x^2 \\ 
    &= \frac12(x-1)^2+\frac12 \\ 
    &\ge \frac12. 
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about this.

Answer (score 26):

If $x=-1$, it is trivial. Otherwise,
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{2n}(-x)^j=\frac{x^{2n+1}+1}{x+1},
$$
and:

- if $x>-1$, the numerator and the denominator of that fraction are both greater than $0$;
- if $x<-1$, the numerator and the denominator of that fraction are both smaller than $0$.

Comment: @rus9384 The missing explanation is: This is the sum of a geometric progression, so it is equal to: $$\text{(first term)}\times\frac{1-\text{(reason)}^\text{(number of terms)}}{1-\text{(reason)}}$$Here the first term is 1, the reason is $-x$, and the number of terms is $2n+1$ which is odd, so $(-x)^{2n+1}=-(x^{2n+1})$

Comment: What do you mean by the "reason"?

Comment: @Someone The constant ratio between each term and the previous one.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps the most straightforward way is to compare individual terms.

First, the trivial cases. If $x<0$ all terms are positive, and if $x=0$ the first term is positive and the rest are $0$. So we just need to deal with $x>0$.

Now the terms are alternating positive and negative. Also the absolute values are either increasing ($x>1$), decreasing ($x<1$) or all equal. If they are increasing then

$$\sum_{j=0}^{2n}(-x)^j=\left(x^{2n}-x^{2n-1}\right)+\cdots+\left(x^{2}-x^{1}\right)+x^0,$$
which is positive because the difference of each pair is positive, as is the unpaired term. If they are decreasing then similarly you can write
$$\sum_{j=0}^{2n}(-x)^j=\left(x^{0}-x^{1}\right)+\cdots+\left(x^{2n-2}-x^{2n-1}\right)+x^{2n},$$
with the same conclusion. If $x=1$ then either of these works (the pairs all contribute $0$ but the remaining term is $1$).

Comment: @Stef no I haven't. If $x<1$ then the lower bound from the unpaired term is $x^{2n}$, which is small. Indeed the sum is always less than $1$ for $0<x<1$, as can be shown by using the "wrong" pairing and noting that the unpaired term is $1$ and the pairs are all negative.

Comment: Oops, I mixed the two pairings in my head